# Trigger HttpHandler on specific URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have made an `HttpHandler` which I want to run when the browser requests something from a specific URL.

I tried registering it like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <clear />
      <add name="png" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.png" type="MyProject.HttpHandler" />
      <add name="jpg" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.jpg" type="MyProject.HttpHandler" />
      <add name="jpeg" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.jpeg" type="MyProject.HttpHandler" />
      <add name="gif" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.gif" type="MyProject.HttpHandler" />
  </handlers>
<system.webServer>
```

This works on all the URLs, except those I need it to work on. The request I want to handle is when the browser requests an image. It looks like this:

`http://example.net/contentassets/some_image_name.jpg?maybe=someParameters`

For some reason the `HttpHandler` isn't picking up those.
Basically I want to use the `HttpHandler` on the requests to `http://example.net/contentassets/...` (so that they only trigger if `contentassets` is in the URL). Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: Does handlers ignore the query string?

EDIT2: We use EPiServer as a CMS, so the images are fetched from the EPiServer blob storage. The storage is inside the project folder. This could maybe be the problem.

Comment: I don't know about EPiServer, but even with a standard IIS/IISExpress, these types of files are served directly by a static filter, so handler don't have any chance to get these requests w/o changing modules and configuration.

Comment: I added the config above to web.config, and it intercepts the requests that else would have gone to the static file handler.

Comment: It really depends on the the server version and how it's configured. On recent versions of IIS/IISExpress, when I mean static, I mean they don't even reach the .NET layer, they are served by IIS itself (but it's still configurable using a .config file). This is for maximum performance. It's important if you plan to use your handler on various real-world configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. EPiServer has its own handler to serve `IContent`, e.g. images, from the BLOB storage. It is possible to create your own handler for specific `IContent` types, overriding EPiServers default implementation.

Here is the implementation from ContentMediaHttpHandler, but set to only trigger on `IContentImage` (images).

```
[TemplateDescriptor(Inherited = true, TemplateTypeCategory = TemplateTypeCategories.HttpHandler)]
public class ImageResizeHandler : BlobHttpHandler, IRenderTemplate<IContentImage>
{
    protected override Blob GetBlob(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
       //This the implementation from ContentMediaHttpHandler
       var downLoadFileName = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.GetCustomRouteData<string>(DownloadMediaRouter.DownloadSegment);
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(downLoadFileName))
       {
           httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", downLoadFileName));
       }

       var routeHelper = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ContentRouteHelper>();
       var binaryStorable = routeHelper.Content as IBinaryStorable;

       return binaryStorable != null ? binaryStorable.BinaryData : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Path element seems to be a mask, have you tried:

```
<add name="png" verb="GET,HEAD" path="*/contentassets/*.png" type="MyProject.HttpHandler" />
```

Comment: That didn't work. We use EPiServer as a CMS, so the images are fetched from the EPiServers blob storage. The storage is a folder inside the project folder. This could maybe be the problem.